# Displaying Contents of Mongodb Database on webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, web-applications

I am trying to display the contents of my database on a webpage.
The way I want to do it is by displaying the content in the database by descending order. I have made the connection to MongoDB and am able to see my data in the terminal stored correctly. I just can't seem to figure out how to display that stored data now.

Thanks!

Server.js file.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/node-demo");

var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Alert: String
});

var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on 3000')
})

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.get('/alertview', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/alertview.html')
})

app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  var myData = new User(req.body);
  myData.save()
    .then(item => {
      res.send("item saved to database");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
});

User.find({},function(err,docs){
       console.log(docs);
   })
```

Html file I want to display the alerts on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/alertpageStyle.css" media="screen" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>View Alerts</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h1>Current Alerts</h1>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should probably look at some templating packages like Ejs, Handlebars or Mustache. Otherwise you would need to look into the fs library with node on creating your html file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256710/display-the-data-onto-webpage-retrieved-from-mongodb-using-node-js
 I found this post and am trying to get it to work but no success yet. I'll look into the templating packages.

Comment: That is using the Jade template http://jade-lang.com/, you need to make sure you are setting up the view engine with express. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple example using the EJS templating, essentially you pass your object to the template at the time of rendering. You can also iterate over data. Same approach can be used for Handlebars or Mustache packages.

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/', index);
```

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```